# Как динамически управлять контентом в ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Начал изучать ASP.NET MVC 5, делаю ToDo-app, и сразу же возник вопрос: как динамически изменять DOM, т.е. например я хочу добавить новое ToDo, нажать кнопку - показать новый элемент, отредактировать его текст и т.д. 
Сейчас я подключил vue.js, и добавляю значения элементов через `@Html.HiddenFor` при добавлении новых ToDo, и соответственно при редактировании - парсю DOM, составляю массив ToDo, отрисовываю их и т.д. средствами vue.js.
Вопрос такой: Есть ли какие то встроенные методы платформы ASP.NET MVC для таких задач? Есть ли какой - то единообразный "правильный подход" для этого? Или в любом случае для динамического контента используются самописные js скрипты?

Comment: AJAX. Пишите на стороне сервера сервис который выдает json/xml с данными по запросу, запрашиваете его через js, парсите и добавляете на клиентскую страницу. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете на сервере прописать несколько методов, который будут возвращать данные в формате JSON и на стороне клиента с помощью JavaScript кода парсить ответ и выводить соответствующую информацию или с помощью того же JS обрабатывать какие-то действия пользователя и менять разметку соответствующим образом.

Предыдущий способ подойдет если вам нужно выполнять мало действий или вы хорошо знакомы с JS чтобы ничего не упустить. Но если действий хотя бы среднее количество, я бы все-таки рекомендовал перейти на Angular c использованием ASP.NET Web API. И уже использовать TypeScript (он и на C# больше походит) и встроенные функции Angular для всего это. Будет гораздо проще, да и нагрузку с сервера на клиента перекинете

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Angular я знаю нормально, и мне самому конечно такой способ (REST + Front) ближе, сейчас у меня просто стоит задача разобраться с самой ASP.NET MVC.